# "Cannot access database on the main thread" Exception in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I built a simple example of Room with LiveData, but get an

> Cannot access database on the main thread"- IllegalStateException

My general architecture is activity with fragment which has a ViewModel & Repository with Room.

My call starts here (I cut out the fragment, its a click on a button which calls the method).

I use androidannotations, but that should not be related to the error.

In my opinion its straight forward and the insert-call is obviously in an AsyncTask, so thats the reason, why im am really confused by the exception.

My ViewModel:

```
class FragmentAddKeywordsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
KeywordsRepository repository;

public FragmentAddKeywordsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    if (repository == null) {
        repository = new KeywordRepository(application);
    }
}

public void addKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
        repository.addKeyword(keyword);
}

}
```

This is my repository:

```
public class KeywordsRepository {
private KeywordDao keywordDao;

public KeywordsRepository (Application application) {
    KeywordDatabase db = KeywordDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    keywordDao= db.keywordDao();

}

public void addKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
    new insertAsyncTask(keywordDao).doInBackground(keyword);
}


private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Keyword, Void, Void> {
    private KeywordDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTask(KeywordDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Keyword... params) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]); // This line throws the exception
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "do in background 1");
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My Database

```
@Database(entities = {Keywords.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class KeywordDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract KeywordsDao keywordDao();

private static KeywordDatabase INSTANCE;

private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback =
        new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onOpen(db);
            }
        };

public static KeywordDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (KeywordDatabase .class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        KeywordDatabase.class, "keywords")
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;

}
}
```

And last but not least my Dao

```
@Dao
interface KeywordDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM keywords")
LiveData<List<Keyword>> getAllKeywords();


@Insert
void insert(Keyword keyword);

@Delete
void delete(Keyword keyword);

@Query("DELETE FROM keywords")
void deleteAll();
}
```

Thats the end of my error stack:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main
>   thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
>   at
>   android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:164)
>   at
>   android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:211)
>   at
>   org.name.project.package.KeywordDao_Impl.insert(KeywordDao_Impl.java:81)
>   at
>   org.name.project.package.KeywordsRepository$insertAsyncTask.doInBackground(KeywordsRepository.java:42)

Comment: You're calling `doInBackground` from the UI thread. Use the `execute` method of `AsyncTask` instead.

Comment: Also right, and first answer, but only a comment :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to call `execute` to let asychtask's `doInBackground` method run in background

```
new insertAsyncTask(keywordDao).execute(keyword);
```

otherwise with this

```
new insertAsyncTask(keywordDao).doInBackground(keyword);
```

you are just calling a method of a class's instance.

Similar example is `Thread` in java where `threadInstance.start()` creates a thread not `threadInstance.run()`

Comment: Right, thanks! It took much much longer to format the code here for stackoverflow as you found the mistake.

Comment: I am glad that we could help though You will get used to it pretty soon,keep it up and Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public void addKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
    new insertAsyncTask(keywordDao).doInBackground(keyword);
}
```

to

```
public void addKeyword(Keyword keyword) {
    new insertAsyncTask(keywordDao).execute(keyword);
}
```

`execute` will call `doInBackground` in a background thread.

Comment: Right, thanks! But I can only chose one answer as right, and pavneet-singh was faster, so...